# Can't process my $_POST data in the server **EDIT** Prepared statements not properly executed

Tags: php, android, mysqli

So I have this scenario. I have an adroid app sending a post variable to a php file on a server. I have a php file on a server that accepts a post variable and executes a function based on the variable recieved.

I can echo these variables and i will recieve them on my device.

I can set the $action variable by myself and it will be processed by the switch as needed.

But I cannot send my own variable and process it as it should be able to.

Ive tried setting the permissions of the php file to 777 and that didnt work.

This is the code below. All the help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');

$action = $_POST['action'];

if(isset($action) && !empty($action)){

        $connection = connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

        switch($action){

            case "sign_up":
            sign_up($connection);
            break;

            case "social_sign_up":
            social_sign_up($connection);
            break;

            case "social_sign_in":
            social_sign_in($connection);
            break;

            case "new_testimony":
            new_testimony($connection);
            break;

            case "new_comment":
            new_comment($connection);
            break;

            case "get_all_testimonies":
            get_all_testimonies($connection);
            break;

            case "get_all_comments":
            get_all_comments($connection);
            break;

            case "sign_in":
            sign_in($connection);
            break;

        }

        mysqli_close($con);

    }

?>
```

**EDIT**
I've isolated the problem to prepared statements that are executed inside the sign_in function.
I've checked that the module exists and it does.
This is the sign in function

```
//sign in
function sign_in($connection){

    if(
        isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) &&
        isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])
    ){


        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $count = NULL;
        $id = NULL;
        $fname = NULL;
        $lname = NULL;

        $stmt = $connection->prepare("select count(*), id, fname, lname from user where email = ? and password = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);

        if($stmt->execute()){

            $stmt->bind_result($count, $id, $fname, $lname);

            $stmt->fetch();


            if($count == 1)
                echo json_encode(array($id, $fname, $lname));
            else
                echo "Ensure your e-mail and password are correct.";

        }

        $stmt->close();

    } echo false;

}
```

I get a fileNotFoundError on my device when i try to echo past the "$stmt = $connection->prepare" point.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: error_reporting has the value "24567" on the info.php page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Comment: still getting a fileNotFoundError @YourCommonSense

Comment: You see, this fileNotFoundError thing is of no help at all. It has nothing to do with prepared statements.

Comment: Actually, knowing the error comes after the prepared statements has now led me to finding out the database connection failed. But my logins are correct, now to find out why.

Comment: mysqli_connect_error() returns "No such file or directory". What does this tell you? I've never met this error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you have an iPage hosted database. While logging in in php. Using 'localhost' or even '127.0.0.1' wont allow you connect. You are given a url that follows the format username.ipagemysql.com. Anything else will throw an error.
Changing my server from 'localhost' to this solved it for me.